# Can I customise PyCharm so that pressing Ctrl+P types print("")?

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard

I'm completely new to programming and thought it would make sense to change my laptop keyboard layout to make it easier to type brackets and quotes. Ideally, I'd like the standard opening and closing brackets () to be where the current squiggly brackets {} are, and the quotation mark " to be where the current @ button is.

That got me thinking that it would be good to be able to press cntrl+P and have that type print(). Or cntl+I and have it print input(""). Ideally the cursor would be placed at the center of the brackets ready to type.

I will be working in cafes on a surfacebook two laptop so a flashed hardware keyboard isn't an option.

Sorry if I'm being dense, I've only been learning for five days and think that right now, whilst using the keys isn't instinctive, it will be the best time to change the standard layout.  I know it's unlikely to save any time but the standard keyboard layout seems to be designed with typists not programmers in mind. I'm using PyCharm.

I tried changing to the Czech programmers keyboard in Windows but didn't like that all the keys did different things, I just want to change the function of a few of them.

The custom keymap in Pycharm seems to just customise shortcuts rather than what is typed when you press particular letters.

Edit- for anyone who has come across this post seeking a similar solution for the keyboard layout, I downloaded PowerToys which allows you to shuffle your keyboard around. Many symbols such as the parenthesis weren't present so it was a bit of trial and error. You need to click on the "Type" heading box to put a ctrl+"something" function on the right side.

```
End to #
[ to shift(right)
] to shift(left)
PgUp to [
PgDn to ]
# to shift(left)
```

These settings kept the ellipses in their traditional place in addition to moving them to the keys previously used for square brackets. The square brackets are now located on the PgUp and PgDn buttons.

The quotation marks are both in their usual place, plus can also be accessed by the hash key button. The hash can now be accessed by pressing the End button. So basically, the brackets and quotation marks are in a triangle towards the right of the keyboard, and accessing them doesn't require Ctrl to be pressed but in case my hands automatically type the usual position it will still be okay.

Comment: `print` and `input` might look important now, when you're only 5 days in, but they're actually quite uncommon in serious code. It's not worth customizing keyboard shortcuts just to type `print` and `input` a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if these are really the shortcuts you want to implement (like user2347112 said print and input will not really be important later on).

However, if you want to have some code snippets to save you some writing time, I would recommend looking into "live snippets", see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tutorial-creating-and-applying-live-templates-code-snippets.html)

Live snippets aren't really shortcuts. You type in the abbreviation, and then "tab" after, and the abbreviation will be exchanged by longer coder. For example when you type in the build in abbreviation `main` and then press tab, the following code will be written

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    $END$
```

$END$ here is the position your cursor is after this.